# Displaying result of random integer in python

Tags: python, random, matrix

```
from random import randint

board = []

for x in range(5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print " ".join(row)

print "Let's play Battleship!"
print_board(board)

def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)

ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)

for turn in range(4):
    guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row:"))
    guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col:"))

    if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
        print "Congratulations! You sunk my battleship!"
        break
    else:
        if (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 4) or (guess_col < 0 or guess_col > 4):
            print "Oops, that's not even in the ocean."
        elif(board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X"):
            print "You guessed that one already."
        else:
            print "You missed my battleship!"
            board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"
    if turn == 3:
        print "Game Over"
    print "Turn", turn + 1
    print_board(board)
```

I've made a simple program through CodeCademy that lets a user play Battleship with a 5x5 matrix, where you try to find a random integer within the matrix. Your hit, regardless of whether or not it is the correct coordinate, is marked by 'X'. I want to figure out how to display what the random coordinate is for each game, after the users 4 chances of guessing have completed. 
For example:

```
Game Over
[0,X,0,0,0]
[X,0,0,[X],0]
[0,0,0,0,X]
[0,0,0,0,0]
[O,0,0,0,0]
```

where the X coordinate in brackets at column 4, row 2 is the correct random coordinate guessed by the user. The X does not have to be in brackets if it conflicts with python syntax, I just want to show the user where in the matrix the correct answer is. Ex:

```
Game Over
[0,X,0,0,0]
[X,0,0,X,0]
[0,0,0,0,X]
[0,0,{0},0,0]
[O,0,0,0,0]
```

This is my first time asking a question using stack overflow, so please correct me if I asked the question wrong.

Comment: You want to 'highlight' the item that is at `board[ship_row][ship_column]`

Comment: just add `board[x][y] = "H"`, `print(board)`, and then `board[x][y] = "X"`, so yo can see the last hit? if @TimCastelijns is correct in deriving your question... The question is kinda unclear... or are you trying to reveal the location of the battleship at the end? `board[shiprow][shipcolumn] = "S"` and then print it at the end?

Comment: That is exactly what he wants to do. This question is as clear as can be

Answer (score 1):

Example using 'S' as the ship character

```
if turn == 3:
    print 'Game Over'
    board[ship_row][ship_col] = 'S'
    print_board(board)
```